Closed formula for a self-expanding quantity (whose rate of growth per year gradually becomes either 1.0001 or 1.999)
Inspiration for this question (So feel free to skip, because this is not relevant to the math):
Chapter 25 of Capital (https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1867-c1/ch25.htm#S2), where Marx says that "All other circumstances remaining the same, individual capitals, and with them the concentration of the means of production, increase in such proportion as they form aliquot parts of the total social capital."
Now, one interpretation of the quote is that from one year to the next year, each capitalist's capital would increase by 1.2 (the same growth ratio is applied to each capitalist). This would keep the proportion of Capitalist B's capital, with respect to the total capital in society the same as before, regardless of the year.
Another interpretation of the quote is that from one year to the next year, each capitalist's capital would increase by (1 + the proportion of that capitalist's capital with respect to the total sum of all capitalist's capital in the society)
$\\$
The mathematical problem is described below:
Let's say we are given the values for the initial amounts of $x_0$, $y_0$, and $z_0$.
We are also given the 2 necessary recurrence relations, namely we are told that from each year to the next, $x_t$ is multiplied by (1 + the current proportion of $x_t$ with respect to $z_t$), and likewise for $y_t$.
At all times t, $z_t = x_t + y_t$
$$x_{t+1} = x_{t}(1 + \frac{x_t}{z_t})$$
$$y_{t+1} = y_{t}(1 + \frac{y_t}{z_t})$$
$$z_{t+1} = x_{t+1} + y_{t+1} = x_{t}(1 + \frac{x_t}{z_t}) + y_{t}(1 + \frac{y_t}{z_t})\\
z_{t+1} = z_{t} + \frac{x_t^2 + y_t^2}{z_t}$$
Since $z_t^2 = x_t^2 + y_t^2 + 2x_ty_t$, therefore $z_{t+1}$ is approximately less than $z_t + z_t$
I know that $z_{t+k} < 2^{k}z_{t}$
My question is:
What are the closed formulas for $x_{t+k}$, $y_{t+k}$, $z_{t+k}$, in terms of only $x_{t}$, $y_{t}$, $z_{t}$, and $k$??
You can feel free to set t to 0.
